# If $^{20}C_r=^{20}C_{r-10}$, find $^rC_{12}$, $^{18}C_r$

Tags: combinatorics

If $^{20}C_r=^{20}C_{r-10}$, find $^rC_{12}$, $^{18}C_r$

To solve this question, the key is to see: $^{20}C_r = ^{20}C_{20-r}=^{20}C_{r-10}$

Then $20-r=r-10 \Rightarrow r=15$ and the question is solved.

My question is since $^{20}C_r = ^{20}C_{20-r}=^{20}C_{r-10}$, why is it if I try $r=20-r \Rightarrow r=10$ and $r=r-10 \Rightarrow 0=-10$, I get answers that are incorrect or nonsensical? But the three combinations equal each other, so what explains this discrepancy? Why is it only $20-r=r-10$ that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $r=20-r$, which implies $r=10$,
the original problem statement says that
$ ^{20}C_{10} = {}^{20}C_0, $
which is clearly not true.

If you set $r=r-10$ then you get $0=-10$, which again is clearly not true.

Two of your three equations for $r$ are false because the fact that
$^{20}C_a = ^{20}C_b$ only **hints** that $a$ and $b$ might be equal.
It makes no guarantee.

When you try to solve an equation, you must reject any "solutions" that make the original equation false. The equation is literally telling you that those "solutions" cannot really be solutions.

When you ignore that requirement, you accept a false statement, and all kinds of false and nonsensical things can be derived from a false statement.

---

In fact it is not a correct method even to say that $20-r=r-10$ merely because $^{20}C_{20-r}={}^{20}C_{r-10}$, and therefore that $r=15$. You must also confirm that $r = 15$ actually makes the original equation true. Otherwise you have not shown that you have a solution.

Rather than fiddle around with algebra, you could use the fact that the $20$th row of Pascal's triangle, which has all the binomial coefficients $^{20}C_0$
through $^{20}C_{20}$, is symmetric. The only way to find two equal numbers on that row is to look at two numbers an equal distance from the center.
Since $r$ and $r-10$ have the difference $10$, you can find the correct entries by starting at the middle ($^{20}C_{10}$), counting $5$ places to the left, and counting $5$ places to the right.
The numbers you will find in those places are the values of
$^{20}C_{15}$ and $^{20}C_{5}$, therefore $r = 15$.

In fact, setting $20 - r = r - 10$ is another way of saying that $r$ and $r-10$ are symmetric places in the $20$th row of Pascal's triangle.
If you understand that **that** is the reason you can set $20 - r = r - 10$,
then you already know that the value of $r$ you will get from that equation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If

$$\binom n k = \binom n t$$

then , **either**
$k=t$ **Or** $k+t=n$ . In other words, it's not necessary that both conditions must satisfy simultaneously.